# Sharepoint lists showing a blank option in all choice fields

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, choice-field

The choice field adds a blank option in all my sharepoint lists. How do I remove this? the column settings does not have a blank option.

[image: blank option in sharepoint list]

[image: choice settings]

Comment: I also have been getting this problem. Never had this before. When did SP start doing this? It has to be fairly new phenomena.

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your issue in my SharePoint Online.

It seems the default behavior in modern list view now, there is a blank option in the choice column even we set the default value.

You can also check the thread:[Spurious blank entry at top of a choice column entry](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Spurious-blank-entry-at-top-of-a-choice-column-entry/m-p/1036324)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Default value` of this column to `open` instead of `None` from column settings (shown in 2nd image).

**Update**:

Following below steps are working for me.
Try below steps and check if it works for you:

1. Go to List Settings.
2. Navigate to Columns section and choose your choice column.
3. At the end of the page, Set `Default value` of this column to `open`.
4. Save.

Comment: tried it doesn't work.

Comment: Try by changing it from list settings.